# Calculating mflop/s of a HPC application using memory bandwidth info

Tags: fortran, mpi, hpc, flops, memory-bandwidth

I want to calculate mflops (million of operations per second per processor) of a HPC application(NAS benchmark) without running the application. I have measured the memory bandwidth of each core of my system (a supercomputer) using Stream Benchmark. I'm wondering how I can get the mflops per processor of the application by having memory bandwidth info of the cores. 
My node has 64GiB memory (includes 16 cores-2 sockets) and 58 GiB/s aggregated bandwidth using all physical cores. The memory bandwidth of my cores are varied from 2728.1204 MB/s to 10948.8962 MB/s for Triad function that it's must be because of NUMA architecture.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: And how many ops are performed for each memory access? OpsPerAccess*MemoryBandwidth/sec = ops/sec

Comment: @enhzflep How can I get the OpsPerAccess? sall I use a tool and use the application there to find it?

Comment: No idea. If you've only got the number of accesses per second, this is the only figure I can imagine that you _could_ use in combination with the only other figure you have - memory bandwidth. Depending on the size of the inner loops, I'd just look at the generated assembly and roughly calculate it by hand. Naturally, this calculation wont take into account things like cache misses etc. Unfortunately, I suspect you've insufficient info to generate anything much better than a vague, rough estimate of performance of your app.

Comment: See http://calcul.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/pdf/Performance.pdf . Let's assume that the bottleneck is a simple operation like AXPY. This operation counts for 2 flops, but 3x8 bytes of memory access. Let's say that my machine has 4 processors and a memory bandwidth of 48 Go/s.  Then, i can perform 48/(3x8)= 2G operations per seconds at most. That's 4Gflops/s, so 1Gflops/s per processor. It's a really rough estimate...

Comment: @francis  Thank you. But I'm not sure if I could follow you. sorry I'm quite new in this field... How did you get 4Gflops/s by having 2G operations per sec? did you multiply 2G by 2flops? "3x8 bytes of memory access" is the memory that cores have access on the system? I've edited my question and added the info that I have about the node. So 64GiB memory per node, is the access memory that you mentioned?

Comment: 1/ If you can do 2G operations per second and if each operation counts for 2 floating point operations, then you can perform 4G floating point operations per second. That's 4Gflop/s. 2/ The operation z=a.x+y will read 2 double (x and y, 8 bytes each) and write 1 (z , 8 bytes). I described that as "3x8 bytes of memory access" (my english is not perfect...). 3/ The performance your are going to get is not related to the size of the memory (64Go on each node), but to the memory bandwidth (58 Go/s). 58Go/s/(3*8)*2=5Gflop/s. If you use 32 processors, it means 160Mflop/s/core (double precision).

Comment: @francis Thanks a lot for the explanation. How can I find the number of floating point operations of my app and the required memory access?(is there any tool? because the application that I have is a benchmark that is quite complicated and written in fortran, not easy to go through the code) besides I'm wondering if you know how I can use the result of stream benchmark which measured the memory bandwidth of each core for finding Mflop/s/core?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get estimate of MFLOPS/GFLOPS of benchmark only from memory bandwidth results from STREAM. You need to know two more parameters: peak MFLOPS/GFLOPS of your CPU core (better as max FLOP operations per clock cycle with all variants of vector instructions and cpu frequency limits: min, mean, max) and also GFLOPS/GBytes (flops to bytes ratio, Arithmetic Intensity) of every program you need to estimate (every NAS Benchmark).

The Stream benchmark has very low arithmetic intensity (0 DP=FP64 flops per two double operands = 2*8 bytes in Copy, 1 flops per 16 bytes in Scale, 1 flops / 24 byte in Add and 2 flops / 24 bytes in Triad). So, Stream benchmark is limited by memory bandwidth in correct runs (and by cache bandwidth in incorrect runs on ). Many benchmarks may have higher

With this data (memory bandwidth, max gflops/GHz on different vectorization levels, normal/maximal/low frequency of cpu, arithmetic intensity of the test) you can start to use roofline performance model https://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/PAR/research/roofline/

[image: Roofline model example; memory limited part]

With roofline you have x axis with flops/byte; y axis of GFlop/s (both are at logarithmic scale). The line of the "roof" consists of two parts for every CPU (or machine).

First part is inclined and corresponds to low arithmetic intensity. Applications in this part will have to wait data to be loaded from memory, they have no data to operate on with full GFlop/s speed of CPU; the tests are limited by memory. This line is defined by STREAM benchmark.

Second part of line is straight, it corresponds to higher intensity. Tasks here are not limited by memory bandwidth, they are limited by available FLOPS. And for modern CPU all flops are available only with wide vector instruction (Instruction-level parallelism), and not all tasks can use widest vectors:

[image: Roofline model; Gflops ILP limited part]